# A good topology for my network

Tags: networking, local-area-network, wide-area-network, wifi

I have this topology in my network at the company where I work:

[image]

Where the only router is the 'main router' (is here where we receive the internet signal from our provider) the others networks points are *switches*, so today my network is in cascade and I wonder if this is the best topology for my network.
If not, what would be ?

EDIT:
This is the structure of the company where I work:

[image]

Comment: A star topology or extended star seems to be how most networks go these days. With added levels of redundancy etc.

Comment: Really depends on the size/data transferred, speed of links between switches. Where are your servers? Do you have any obvious bottlenecks? Are your switches managed or unmnanaged?

Comment: It's a company with 17 computer connected. We don't have any server by our own. We don't have bottleneck so far, but we have problems if some switch is not working okay, then part of the network start to have issues too. Our switches are unmanaged.

Comment: for 17 machines, you should be able to just buy a 24 port switch and a spare one in case it breaks or a pair of 48 ports if you predict expansion. This assumes geographical separation isn't an issue.

Comment: +1. This is tiny - my office of 3 people uses a 24 switch port just for itself.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers my question is if there's another topology better than the actual ?

Comment: @Valter, unless you are actually routing through those systems as suggested by your top diagram that's not an illustration of your network structure, which makes it rather difficult to comment on in a useful manner. Nevertheless, based on what you've written I have to agree with others that you only need a single switch, preferably placed physically somewhere near the middle of your network, so as to keep cabling runs as short as practical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With only 17 computers, you really should only be on a single 24 port switch. This is assuming that home run cable pulls aren't out of the question for some reason.

You may not be seeing any bottlenecks right now, but are introducing points of failure, and additional overhead when it comes to troubleshooting. You are also giving employees the ability to plug devices into your network without your knowledge.

As a side note, I once saw a general manager of a hotel plug a WAP into an extra port in his office which went unnoticed for about a week and hotel guests were connecting to it as if it were an open AP. That would be one of my bigger concerns with your setup.

Comment: Have to agree with this. A good topology/design mantra for a network is "Design the simplest thing possible that solves the problem. Then stop." and plugging multiple devices into one another does not meet this ideal. In your circumstances here, if you need more than one switch due to geographical reasons, I'd still limit myself to as few as possible, all of which should be plugged directly into the "central" core switch, not into each other.

Comment: A switch with 24/48 ports would be nice, but the structure of the building would demand pulling too many cables.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other comments that a single switch should suffice, but I think the best answer also depends on the physical lay-out of your office. If you need very long cable runs to accommodate say 5 of your users, you might opt to run a single cable and deploy a desk switch instead.

Comment: But if you have to run one, you may as well run a bundle.

Comment: Agree with Dan. The expensive part of that is the time of the person doing it and making good any structural changes from pulling the cable. The costs for pulling 10 cables instead of just 1 through that run really shouldn't be that different.

Comment: Good point. If I could, I would. But we still don't know much about the physical lay-out, which might constrain the number of cables.

Comment: @Sagi I update my post to show you guys how is my structure here in the company.

Comment: It seems to me you should be able to drop a bundle from the 3rd floor all the way to the router and distribute accordingly. I did cabling for a long time, as long as you are within the length limits of the cable, it will be well worth it in the long run.

Comment: @DanBig, you're saying that I should have a switch in the 3rd floor then cabling top-down from there ? What this gonna improve my network ?

Comment: No, its usually easier to drop cable down, than run it up floors. Once the bundle is the whole length, peel off the necessary runs for each floor, all terminated into wall jacks and a patch panel at your router.